# Adding robots.txt to Expo for web

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I'm building across native and web with Expo 49. For the web version, I need to add a /robots.txt route, and other similar paths.

In my /app directory, I tried adding an escaped path to ensure it resolves with the `.txt`:

`/app/robots[.]txt.tsx`

But it didn't work. Expo redirects to `[...missing].tsx`.

And of course this works:
`/app/robots.tsx`

But then it resolves to the path: `/robots` which is not correct.

Is there another way to do this? If not allowing the path as robots.txt, then adding the .txt in the static web build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a `public` directory in the root and added robots.txt there, and then built the web version and served it:

```
npx expo export -p web
npx serve dist
```

Now robots.txt is available at localhost:3000/robots.txt